# Jquery / Javascript - Add years to date variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small trouble that would be great to have some help with. I am creating a small form that I want to take a current date formatted `'dd/mm/yyyy'` and add a year(s) variable from a drop-down box to create a final expiry date. The only trouble is that I do not know how to parse the start-date as a date variable in order to complete the calculation. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated. Paul.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#registerfor, #startdate, ").change(function () {
            // Get Variables
            var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
            var registerfor = $("#registerfor").val();
            // Add Years to Date
            var expirydate = startdate + registerfor;
            // Send Result on
            $("#expires").val(expirydate);
        });
    });
</script>
<input name="startdate" id="startdate" value="dd/mm/yyyy" />
<select id="registerfor" name="registerfor">
    <option value="1">1 Year</option>
    <option value="2">2 Years</option>
    <option value="3">3 Years</option>
</select>
```

Comment: are you using any jquery for this?

Comment: Hi @kash yes I am hoping to use Jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes what looks like quite a straight forward task becomes quite complicated.

```
 $(document).ready( function () {

    $("#registerfor, #startdate").change( function () {

        var str = $("#startdate").val();

        if( /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/i.test( str ) ) {

            var parts = str.split("/");

            var day = parts[0] && parseInt( parts[0], 10 );
            var month = parts[1] && parseInt( parts[1], 10 );
            var year = parts[2] && parseInt( parts[2], 10 );
            var duration = parseInt( $("#registerfor").val(), 10);

            if( day <= 31 && day >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1 ) {

                var expiryDate = new Date( year, month - 1, day );
                expiryDate.setFullYear( expiryDate.getFullYear() + duration );

                var day = ( '0' + expiryDate.getDate() ).slice( -2 );
                var month = ( '0' + ( expiryDate.getMonth() + 1 ) ).slice( -2 );
                var year = expiryDate.getFullYear();

                $("#expires").val( day + "/" + month + "/" + year );

            } else {
                // display error message
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/fgtw8/2/) is a fiddle so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks heaps Bruno. Seriously it is very much appreciated!

Comment: seems too complicated, the response below sound better

Answer (score 36):

A quick and easy solution :

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + nbYearsToAdd);
```

"nbYearsToAdd" can be negative.

Comment: use `setFullYear` since `setYear ` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = new Date($("#startdate").val());

var updateDate = dt.setDate(dt.getFullYear() + $("#registerfor").val());

var dd = updateDate.getDate();
var mm = updateDate.getMonth();
var y = updateDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
console.log(someFormattedDate);
```

Comment: Hi @don, I appreciate your thoughts, though I really am struggling to make your solution work. I do see the logic, but it won't implement to suit the solution. If I want to add 2 years to 02/10/2012 so that the expiry field displays 02/10/2014 the above solution is not behaving itself. I appreciate your thoughts and your input though.

Comment: Sorry mate. This piece of code is getting the better of me. It doesn't convert to a date unfortunately. I did an alert check and var updateDate returns a string similar to 3074335200000 so getting the month / day / year out of that is where it's misbehaving.

Comment: @DOM, you meaning setFullYear instead of setDate, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it's already working. If you still want to convert in date then do this:

```
var dat=Date.parse(startdate );
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, Wish it was working. The above code produces an outcome similar to 05/10/20122 and By parsing the date all I get is a figure that looks similar to: 13365720000002

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- put the date in a format that Date.parse can work nicely with (mm/dd/yyyy)
- add the number of milliseconds in a year times the selected option
- Reformat the new value to a human-readable format and populate #expires

  `var dateArr = $("#startdate").val().split();`
  `var niceDate = Number(dateArr[1]) + "/" + Number(dateArr[0]) + "/" +  Number(dateArr[2]);`


  `var expDate = Date.parse(niceDate) + 365*24*60*60*1000*Number($("#registerfor").val());`
  `$("#expires").val(expDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + expDate.getDate() + "/" + expDate.getFullYear());`

If you need 2-digit days and months for expiration date, you could have extra variables that hold a string version of them and check something like:
    `var padMonth = expDate.getMonth()+1;`
    `if(expDate.getMonth()+1 < 10) padMonth = "0" + Number(expDate.getMonth()+1);`

After which, you would use padMonth in $("#expires").val(...)

Answer (score -1):

lots of date picker jquery are available on the net

[This](http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=doc)

one is my favourite, easy to implement and edit as per our needs.

if you want to use script from your code, you can directly pass the date value to **var startdate** like

```
var startdate=<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>
```

try this.. may help.

Comment: Hi Kash, thank you for your response, though unfortunately I need to send the variable from an established field and so I wouldn't be able to utilise your suggestion. Cheers for your thoughts though.